# Error in running sonarqube from GitLab CI

Tags: java, maven, continuous-integration, gitlab, sonarqube

I am using Sonarqube to optimize my code quality in my project and I tried adding it to my CI cycle on GitLab but I am getting an error. When I just run mvn sonar:sonar in my IntelliJ terminal it works, but it somehow throws an error while executed in my GitLab CI. The error is:

> Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.7.0.1746:sonar (default-cli) on project rlstop: Your project contains .java files, please provide compiled classes with sonar.java.binaries property, or exclude them from the analysis with sonar.exclusions property.

My gitlab-ci.yml:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - sonarqube
build:
  script: "mvn compile"
test:
  script: "mvn test"
  stage: test
sonarqube:
  script: "mvn sonar:sonar"
  stage: sonarqube
```

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
spring.datasource.url=...
spring.datasource.username=...
spring.datasource.password=...
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql = true

## Hibernate Properties
# The SQL dialect makes Hibernate generate better SQL for the chosen database
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect

# Hibernate ddl auto (create, create-drop, validate, update)
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update

sonar.java.binaries=bin
```

Does anybody know what this error means and how to resolve it?

Comment: Use `mvn compile sonar:sonar -Dsonar.java.binaries=target/classes`.

Comment: Then I get the error > No files nor directories matching 'target/classes'

Comment: Did you add the `compile`?

Comment: I initially tried it with adding ```<sonar-java-binaries>target/classes</sonar-java-binaries>``` to my pom.xml properties, which gave the error specified in the previous comment. When I put your solution in the script in the yml, I get the following error: ```Unknown lifecycle phase ".java.binaries=target/classes". You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are:``` 1/2

Comment: 2/2 ```validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.```

Comment: Have you tried using `mvn compile sonar:sonar` instead of `mvn sonar:sonar` (with `<sonar-java-binaries>target/classes</sonar-java-binaries>`)?

Comment: @dan1st This indeed fixed my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The error mentioned that you need to provide the compiled classes of java using `sonar.java.binaries`

In your .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:
  - build
  - test
  - sonarqube
build:
  stage: build
  script: "mvn compile"
test:
  stage: test
  script: "mvn test"
sonarqube:
  stage: sonarqube
  script: "mvn -U install sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=Gitlab-CI -Dsonar.projectName=Gitlab-CI -Dsonar.sources=. -Dsonar.java.binaries=**/* -Dsonar.language=java"
```

If in case you have added `<sonar-java-binaries>target/classes</sonar-java-binaries>` in your pom.xml, please remove. Only, have the entry of maven-sonar-plugin in the plugins section of pom.xml

Hope this might help you.

Comment: `sonar.java.binaries=**/* ` did the trick, thank you so much!