# Review of gitlab CI using yml

Tags: java, maven, gitlab, continuous-integration, yaml

Hi I am using the following gitlab yml file for setting up my pipeline. The project is a maven Java project. But I am not able to run all the steps successfully. Here is the gitlab yml:

```
image: maven:3.5-jdk-8

variables:
   MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"
   MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

include:
    - template: Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml

cache:
  paths:
    - .m2/settings.xml

# Define stages
#   Stages group various steps into one block,
#   if any step fails, the entire stage fails
stages:
  - validate
  - compile
  - SonarQube
  - test
  
validate: 
  stage: validate
  script:
    - mvn validate

compile:
  stage: compile
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS compile
  
sonarqube-check:
  image: maven:3.6.3-jdk-11
  stage: SonarQube 
  variables:
    SONAR_USER_HOME: "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/.sonar"
  script:
    - mvn sonar:sonar -Dsonar.projectKey=key -Dsonar.host.url=url -Dsonar.login=id
  allow_failure: true

spotbugs-sast:
  variables:
    COMPILE: "false"
    SECURE_LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
  artifacts:
    reports:
      sast: gl-sast-report.json


#spotbugs-sast:
#  variables:
#    SECURE_LOG_LEVEL: "debug"
    #FAIL_NEVER: 1

test:
  image: maven:3.5-jdk-8
  stage: test
  script:
    - mkdir -p /opt/path/conf/project/
    - echo ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}
    - cp "${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/project.properties" "/opt/path/conf/project/"
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS test -B
```

But I am getting errors in stages: sonarqube, spotbug-sast and test.

1. In sonarqube, it isshowing error as: Failed to resolve the project dependency with a list of jar files as:

The following artifacts could not be resolved: webpay:webpay-client:jar:4.0.4, mpienhanced:mpienhanced:jar:1.0.0, webpay:webpay-mpi:jar:4.3.9, webpay:matrix-mpi:jar:1.27.4, webpay:vbv-matrix:jar:1.12.1, webpay:xercesImpl:jar:2.12.0, webpay:xss4j:jar:0.0.1, webpay:xmlParserAPIs:jar:2.11.0, webpay:webpay-mpi-util:jar:4.2.2

1. In spotbugs-sast I am getting the error as:
   [INFO] [Find Security Bugs] [2022-01-13T10:41:39Z] ▶ Found 1 analyzable projects.
   [FATA] [Find Security Bugs] [2022-01-13T10:41:39Z] ▶ lstat /root/.m2/repository: no such file or directory
2. In test stage it is not able to get the properties file from the path that is mentioned in the config file. I have tried to place the properties file at all the places and specify the path but to no luck.

Can someone please help resolve my issues. Thanks in advance.
Let me know if any additional info is required.

Comment: Are you running each stage using a different image?

Comment: No, I have tried running each stage by using a global image as well, but not luck

Comment: Ok, do you want first to try with the `SonarQube` stage? Could you try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64336261/3301492) approach?

Comment: Tried the given answers but still getting same errors. Failed to execute goals.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could try going back to  a [documentation example](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#pre-compilation) and tweak it to incrementally make it like the one in your question.

But be warned: spotbugs-sast won't analyze Java much longer.

See [GitLab 14.10](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/04/22/gitlab-14-10-released/#faster-easier-java-scanning-in-sast) (April 2022)

> ### Faster, easier Java scanning in SAST
>
> GitLab Static Application Security Testing (SAST) now uses Semgrep to scan Java code, building on previous support for [Go (introduced in GitLab 14.4)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/10/22/gitlab-14-4-released/#semgrep-sast-analyzer-for-go) and for [JavaScript, TypeScript, and Python (introduced in GitLab 13.12)](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2021/05/22/gitlab-13-12-released/#semgrep-sast-analyzer-for-javascript-typescript-and-python).
>
> The Semgrep-based analyzer runs significantly faster—up to 7 times faster in our testing than the existing analyzer that’s based on SpotBugs.
> It also doesn’t need to compile your code before scanning, so it’s much simpler to use than SpotBugs.
>
> The Static Analysis and Vulnerability Research teams worked together to translate rules to the Semgrep format, preserving most existing rules.
> We also updated, refined, and tested the rules as we converted them.
>
> If you use [the GitLab-managed SAST template](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#configure-sast-manually) ([`SAST.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml)), both Semgrep and SpotBugs now run whenever Java code is found.
> In GitLab Ultimate, the Security Dashboard combines findings from the two analyzers, so you won’t see duplicate vulnerability reports.
>
> In GitLab 15.0, as [we announced](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/update/deprecations#sast-analyzer-consolidation-and-cicd-template-changes), we’ll change [the GitLab-managed SAST template](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#configure-sast-manually) ([`SAST.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml)) to **only run the Semgrep-based analyzer for Java code**.
> The **SpotBugs-based analyzer will still scan other JVM languages like Groovy, Kotlin, and Scala**.
>
> If you have any questions, feedback, or issues with the new Semgrep-based Java scanning, please [file an issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/new?issuable_template=Bug&add_related_issue=352666&issue%5Btitle%5D=Feedback%20on%20SAST%20Semgrep%20Java%20support&issue%5Bdescription%5D=%2Flabel%20%7E%22group%3A%3Astatic%20analysis%22), we’ll be glad to help.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#supported-languages-and-frameworks) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/352666).

---

And [GitLab 15.1](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/06/22/gitlab-15-1-released/#static-analysis-analyzer-updates) (June 2022) adds improvements which could help:

> ### Static Analysis analyzer updates
>
> GitLab Static Analysis includes [many security analyzers](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#supported-languages-and-frameworks) that the GitLab Static Analysis team actively manages, maintains, and updates. The following analyzer updates were published during the 15.1 release milestone. These updates bring additional coverage, bug fixes, and improvements.
>
> - Secret Detection analyzer updated for better offline support and easier debugging. See [CHANGELOG](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/secrets/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v404) for details.
>
>   - Improve logging
>   - Use checked-out copy of the repository if `git fetch` fails
>   - Fall back to scanning the latest commit if automatic diff detection fails
> - SpotBugs analyzer updated to SpotBugs version 4.7.0 and find-sec-bugs version 1.12.0. See [CHANGELOG](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/security-products/analyzers/spotbugs/-/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v310) for details.
>
>   - Update `gradle` and `grails` to support Java 17
>   - Set Java 17 as the system-wide default version
>   - Use ‘assemble’ task for Gradle projects, instead of ‘build’, to support custom `GRADLE_CLI_OPTS` (see [issue #299872](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/299872))
>   - Add additional detection rules
>
> If you [include the GitLab-managed SAST template](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#configure-sast-manually) ([`SAST.gitlab-ci.yml`](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/blob/master/lib/gitlab/ci/templates/Security/SAST.gitlab-ci.yml)), you don’t need to do anything to receive these updates. However, if you override or customize your own CI/CD template, you need to update your CI/CD configurations.
>
> To remain on a specific version of any analyzer, you can [pin to a minor version of an analyzer](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/#pinning-to-minor-image-version). Pinning to a previous version prevents you from receiving automatic analyzer updates and requires you to manually bump your analyzer version in your CI/CD template.
>
> For previous changes, see [last month’s updates](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/05/22/gitlab-15-0-released/#static-analysis-analyzer-updates).
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/application_security/sast/analyzers) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/361838#new-monthly-analyzer-updates).